# Poser with cutting string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have this `string` which contains HTML code:

```
....
....
<span class="sss">some word</span>
....
....
```

How can I take only text from this line, in my case `some word`. I tried to do this using the `substr` and `strpos` functions. But, I have some problem.

- Closing `</span>` tags were encountered in the string before
- I do not know how long the text will be (in my case `some word`)

P.S That text not only non-html portion of the string value

Comment: Will that text be the only non-html portion of the string value? You could use `strip_tags` if it is.

Comment: Use HTML parser  if it is valid HTML.

Comment: I would use the Symfony DomCrawler component: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

Comment: Just use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)/[Xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), plenty of examples on the interwebs but here's a copy and paste solution... https://3v4l.org/RDdOr

Comment: @IncredibleHat, No

Comment: If no, then pour into DOMDocument like Lawrence mentioned.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, thats work. Thanks))